# Simple Calculator (C#) - How do I get result of calculation involving two integers in textBox2?

Tags: c#

I'm still fairly new to C# programming language. I have to create a simple calculator which can add, subtract, multiply, divide two numbers of users choice without decimals. My Calculator has two input text boxes and one output text box. I've only got 4 operator buttons which are; +,-,*,/. In addition, I also added a 'Backspace' button.

When user inputs the two values, they have to press one of the operator buttons. For example; if the user types in 10 in 'textBox1' and 20 in 'textBox2' and presses 'Button15', the value of the sum will be displayed in 'textBox2'.

There is link of image below the code.

So my problem is with the code under "=" Button15 - I am able to display my user input values but there is problem with my result. I have used my own approach and it might be incorrect.

I would appreciate any help.

Here's the source code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int FirstNumber;
    string Operation;
    string l;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(textBox1.Text=="0")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "6";
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "6";
        }
    }

    private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int SecondNumber;
        int Result;

        if (Operation == "+")
        {
            string l = textBox1.Text;
            int index = l.IndexOf("+");
            string result = l.Substring(index + 1);
            SecondNumber = Convert.ToInt16(result);
            Result = (FirstNumber + SecondNumber);
            textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(Result);


        }
        else if (Operation == "-")
        {
            string l = textBox1.Text;
            int index = l.IndexOf("-");
            string result = l.Substring(index + 1);
            SecondNumber = Convert.ToInt16(result);
            Result = (FirstNumber - SecondNumber);
            textBox2.Text = Result.ToString(); 

        }
        else if (Operation == "x")
        {
            string l = textBox1.Text;
            int index = l.IndexOf("x");
            string result = l.Substring(index + 1);
            SecondNumber = Convert.ToInt16(result);
            Result = (FirstNumber * SecondNumber);
            textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(Result);

        }
        else if(Operation=="/")
        {
            string l = textBox1.Text;
            int index = l.IndexOf("/");
            string result = l.Substring(index + 1);
            SecondNumber = Convert.ToInt16(result);
            if ( SecondNumber == 0)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "Cannot divide by 0";
            }
            else
            {
                Result = (FirstNumber / SecondNumber);
                textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(Result);
            }
        }



    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)      
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "1";
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "1";
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "2";
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "2";
        }

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "3";
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "3";
        }
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "5";
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "5";
        }
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "4";
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "4";
        }
    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "7";
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "7";
        }
    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "8";
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "8";
        }
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "0")
        {
            textBox1.Text = "9";
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "9";
        }
    }

    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "0";

    }

    private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       int FirstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        string Operation = "-";

        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Operation;


    }

    private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int FirstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        string Operation = "+";
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Operation;


    }

    private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int FirstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        string Operation = "x";
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Operation;


    }

    private void button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int FirstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        string Operation = "/";
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Operation;

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int FirstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "0";
    }


    private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "0";
    }
```

[Here is the image of my calculator. The textBox1, the one at the top is happily displaying the user input but the one below, textBox2 is not working when clicked on "="](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QemyQ.jpg)

Comment: You should strongly consider giving your buttons (and the event handlers for them)  meaningful names.

Comment: Yes I will consider it. Thanks :)

Comment: You are not setting the value of the form field `Operation`. You create a _new_ local variable called `Operation` in some of the event handlers. I recommend you learn to use the debugger and pay attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: um Okay...So what's wrong with the code exactly?..Sorry I'm dumb..can you write  correct code for me..

Comment: okay but i didn't asked the whole code - i asked only part of code which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

In your button event handlers you declare new `FirstNumber` and `Operation` variables and assign them. These aren't the same as the Form's `FirstNumber` and `Operation`. You don't need to declare them again, you can just assign to them.

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   int FirstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    string Operation = "-";

    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Operation;


}
```

should be

```
private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    FirstNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    Operation = "-";

    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + Operation;
}
```

and similar for the rest of your button clicked event handlers.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I could have figured that out my own.

Comment: Great! It takes a little while to get familiar with things. The same concept here applies to instances of objects too, where you have a class which describes the object(size, position, functions), and you can instantiate or make an active copy of that class as variables.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please give dhe controls and event handlers meaningful names. You can change the name in the properties columns in Design View.

Secondly, you declare **new variables** in the methods for handling operator button clicks.
For example, you have `int FirstNumber` and `string Operation` in the event handlers. After the declaration the class variables with the same name are shadowed, and you access only the new variables inside those handlers.

Remove the `int` and `string`. The way you have it, you never change the class fields.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!